# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.Raw.ICoreWebView2Controller'

Tags: c#

I am getting the below exception from wpf application webview2 control.

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.Raw.ICoreWebView2Controller'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{4D00C0D1-9434-4EB6-8078-8697A560334F}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))

It seems it goes GC.Finalisethread from GUI thread. How can I resolve this.